# GRUB 0.97: vga=xxx not working with EL TORITO boot image

Tags: boot, grub, vga, el-torito

Currently I'm programming an operating system. Therfore I'm using GRUB 0.97 (legacy) as the bootloader... As standard it puts out a 80x25 text mode. Of course I want a higher resolution... I've already read about the flag "vga=xxx" on the GNU GRUB website. I placed it into the menu.lst file:

```
default 0
kernel os/kernel.img vga=792
boot
```

But the 80x25 interface still keeps. Could someone help me to fix it? Thank you for advice

Answer (score 0):

`vga=792` is a Linux kernel parameter. GRUB only passes it to the kernel image and does nothing else with it.

If the special handling of the `vga=` option in GRUB 0.97 source code gives you a different impression, it's perhaps because the `vga=` option is not the *original* way of setting Linux display modes. Before the concept of *kernel command line parameters* existed, the very early versions of Linux had a few fixed locations for parameters in the kernel image header: those could be modified by editing the kernel image file with a suitable tool, or the bootloader could update those values as it loaded the kernel image to memory.

GRUB 0.97 still maintains compatibility with those early kernel versions and their more limited configuration mechanism: the `vga=...` value is passed to the kernel as a regular kernel parameter, and the display mode value is also updated to the legacy location in the kernel image header as the kernel image is loaded.

As you write a display driver for your operating system, one of its functions will have to be setting a display resolution (or *video mode*). `vga=792` is the Linux `vesafb` mode value for the 1024x768 resolution with 16M colours. So you might want to study [Linux's `vesafb` framebuffer display driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/video/fbdev/vesafb.c).

If you want an easier option, you might use the (S)VGA text modes instead, like Linux's [old vgacon text-only console driver does](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/video/console/vgacon.c). It looks like switching to a higher-resolution text mode is basically just setting a few new values in the mode control registers of a VGA-compatible display controller, and keeping track of the size of the display memory required for the display at the chosen resolution.

A Linux kernel with a `vga=...` parameter will switch video modes almost immediately after the kernel begins executing. It happens so fast, it might look like GRUB is doing it, but GRUB 0.97 has no code for video mode switching (unless patched to display a boot logo, as I think some distributions did - I have no clue as to how those patches might have worked).